# Sharing files present in google drive with a web app

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible for a user to share a file directly with a web app.
This is what I am envisioning. User A sends a request to userB to upload a document. User B logs in to our site and either uploads a document directly,

or

clicks on a link that lets him share files already in google drive.
The only requirement is that userB is someone able to share files in his drive with the webapp , and userA gets the notification through the App.
Also userA can access the file through his dashboard in the web app.

I am using ruby on rails specifically , but I couldn't find any gem that lets users share files present in drive.

I found this link.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/share-button

But am not sure if this is what I want. I want to create a share button upon clicking user can select a file in his google drive and share with the web app , and then user A can click on it and open it in google drive.

Comment: Yes. Checkout the [Manage Sharing](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing) guide in Drive API where you'll be using [permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create) to assign [permission](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-permissions) to a file.

Comment: But how will the web app have file id.

Comment: web apps dont have fileIDs. Drive files have fileIDs

Comment: Yeah i mean .. how will my application abc.com know the fileID of a file in drive , that a user of our application wants to share with us.